# How to enable react-jsonschema-form themes when using the CDN library

Tags: reactjs, cdn, react-jsonschema-forms

I have a massive JSON schema and I want to generate an HTML/JS form from it. It appears that the `react-jsonschema-form` is a good solution to this problem. The framework has great documentation, but it focuses on development using npm. For reasons that are out of scope for this question, I have to use it only via CDN + React without JSX. Unfortunately, I am not a Web developer and I am having a hard time to figure out how I can use different themes when developing with the CDN + React with no JSX. For far I have the following `index.html` working as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script src="react.development.js"></script>
        <script src="react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="react-jsonschema-form.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          const schema = {
            title: "Todo",
            type: "object",
            required: ["title"],
            properties: {
              title: {type: "string", title: "Title", default: "A new task"}
            }
          };
          var e = React.createElement;
          const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;
          ReactDOM.render(
            e(Form, {schema: schema}),
            document.getElementById("app")
          );
        </script>
      </body>
</html>
```

The .js files are downloaded and copied in the same directory with `index.html`. I am using version 2.5.1 of `react-jsonschema-form`.

I would be more than grateful if someone could point me to the right direction as to how I can render this using the different themes of the framework (e.g., Material UI).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your HTML is only missing the inclusion of the CSS

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
```